# Not sure if I should use a scrollview or tableview when making a upload form

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am trying to build a upload form in my app but I dont know if I should use a scrollview or a tableview.

You should be able to fill in some text inputs, add some images and pick a category.

The form also needs to be somewhat dynamic, - Based on what the user types it should show or hide some of the textinputs.

What I understand so far is that a tableview works better when it comes to memory, but I want to know if there is any others pros / cons between the two.

Since I am new to Swift/ios dev I would appreciate any code example when it comes to making tableview-forms

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can provide some mockup image of what you are trying to achieve? If you have a lot a replicated fields that needs a the same treatment, then maybe a tableview is best, otherwise i would just use a scrollview. Remenber that a tableview is a scrollview, with some optimization stuff added on top..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It will look like this: 2x text input and 1x multiline text input, and you will be able to pick 5 images to upload and lastly a category picker (segues to another tableview populated by categories) So a total of 5x different elements

Answer (score -1):

There are many libraries already made for this if you want to learn how to use external libraries. It is great fun and time-saving:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=form

Comment: Thanks found some interesting! But I would really like to know what the big pro/con is when you choose between a tableview/scrollview when making a form :)